# Mapping multiple historical routes from lists of points

Tags: qgis, csv, historical-maps

I'm working with a spreadsheet of data culled from historical archives, in which I've got a list of travelers, each with a start location and an end location (lat/long). Some also have known intermediate stopping points, but not all. What I *want* to do in qgis or arcgis is map each of these people's travels as a separate line/route made up of two to five connected points. Is it possible to do this? Am I missing an obvious solution?

I'm pushing up against the limits of my autodidact humanities-person GIS skills. I can figure out how to create a layer (from a CSV file) marking *one* point per person, but beyond that I am stuck. There are a couple of hundred people involved, meaning drawing the routes manually is really not optimal.

I can kludge together more or less the right result in Palladio, the Stanford digital humanities app (http://hdlab.stanford.edu/palladio/), where it ends up looking something like this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy1ha.jpg

But Palladio is rather awkward/limited for this purpose, and there's no way to join together line segments belonging to the same person's journey, or to export or save the results for use in other GIS software.

Comment: can you show us a few example lines from the CSV file?

Comment: The imgur link fails to display

Answer (score 3):

Here are two different methods. Each method requires a different spreadsheet setup. I recommend choosing whichever option requires the least manipulation of your spreadsheet.

**Option one: Make each point location a separate line in the CSV file.**

Add a new field "order", where "order"=1 means this is the start point, "order"=2 is the next point on the path, and so on. If your data already has a date field for each point, you can use the date instead of creating a new field.

Example: Let's say you have a traveler named Susan, who starts at the lat/long point (55.0, 90.1), passes through an intermediate point (56.9, 90.5), and ends at the point (59.2, 97.3). Your CSV for Susan should look like this:

```
Name | Order | Lat | Long
Susan | 1 | 55.0 | 90.1
Susan | 2 | 56.9 | 90.5
Susan | 3 | 59.2 | 97.3
```

**Import the CSV into QGIS, and use `points to path` to create lines connecting the separate points.** Use "order" as the order field, and "name" as the "group" field.

[image]

---

**Option two: Add a [WKT-formatted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) geometry column to the CSV.**

The WKT geometry for a line looks like this: `LINESTRING (X1 Y1, X2 Y2, X3 Y3)`

In the example I used above with the traveler named Susan, your spreadsheet should look like this:

```
Name | WKTGeometry
Susan | LINESTRING (90.1 55.0, 90.5 56.9, 97.3 59.2)
```

Notice that the coordinate order is reversed, so they're listed with longitude first and latitude second.

**When you import the CSV into QGIS, choose Well Known Text (WKT) for the Geometry Definition.**

[image]